# sources for beeping sound

Tags: debian, audio, hardware

My problem, is, that I'm not able to disable the beeping, when plugging and unplugging the charger and opening the laptop (wake up?).

I have tried to disable the bell, with xset, rmmod and blacklisting the pcspkr module, however without any success. `xset -q` reports, that the bell is indeed muted, the pcspkr module is not listed in `lsmod`. And `rmmod -v` returns no such file or directory.

I'm thinking, that the beeping comes from an other, maybe hardware, source. But I don't know how to get any further from this point on. Has anybody an idea what the problem could be?

I'm running dwm on debian stable on a thinkpad R400.

Comment: does it beep when you are in BIOS screen?

Comment: yes thank you. I fugured it out, it was a BIOS setting

Answer (score 1):

I figuerd it out, it was a BIOS setting.
Disable Config->Beep and Alarm->Power Control Beep

Comment: Are you under some NDA which prevents you from telling which BIOS settings exactly and how to change it?

Comment: no but it is pretty self explonaring: Config->Beep and Alarm->Power Control Beep